# location (alias) block gives forbidden

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

When i access http://my_ip/cachet/ i get a forbidden error

```
location /cachet/ {
    alias /var/www/cachet/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

When i go to http://my_ip/cachet/index.php it says "File not found."

Nginx should be able to read the `cachet` folder

```
drwxr-xr-x 13 www-data www-data 4096 jan 27 01:26 cachet
```

Running PHP and nginx process:

```
root@h2638935:/var/www# ps aux -P | grep nginx
root     21623  0.0  0.0 125756  1684 ?        Ss   01:43   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data 21624  0.0  0.0 125756  2300 ?        S    01:43   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 21625  0.0  0.0 125756  2992 ?        S    01:43   0:00 nginx: worker process
root     21636  0.0  0.0  12888  1120 pts/0    S+   01:50   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
root@h2638935:/var/www# ps aux -P | grep php
root     17562  0.0  0.4 280252 19476 ?        Ss   jan26   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data 17563  0.0  0.6 285472 26408 ?        S    jan26   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 17564  0.0  0.6 285792 26708 ?        S    jan26   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
root     21638  0.0  0.0  12888  1116 pts/0    S+   01:50   0:00 grep --color=auto php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
location ^~ /cachet/ {
    alias /var/www/cachet/public/;
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /cachet/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

- The location and alias values should either both end in `/` or neither end in `/`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for more.
- Don't use `alias` and `try_files` together. See [this long term issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) and [this caution using `if`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).
- Use `$request_filename` to obtain the aliased pathname.

Answer (score 0):

Never forget the behavior of the try_files directive: 
The last param of the `try_files` directive leads to a re-evaluation of ALL `location` blocks in the current scope (usually `server`).

The `/index.php?$query_string;` doesn't match the `/cachet/` prefix and therefore your nested location for the PHP Engine is never reached.